# ¿Cómo esperar que que terminen todos los hilos iniciados en Delphi?

Tags: hilos, delphi, multitasking

Estoy estudiando el tema de hilos por primera vez, empecé con este [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451813/7619298):

Acá defino mi clase de tipo Hilo

```
  TMyWorkerThread = class(TThread)
    procedure DoSomeWork();
  private
    FidHilo : string;
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(pTxt: string);
    property idHilo : string read FidHilo write FidHilo;
  end;
```

Construyo un instancia

```
constructor TMyWorkerThread.Create(pTxt: string);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FidHilo := pTxt;
end;
```

E imediatamente pasa al `Execute`

```
procedure TMyWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  DoSomeWork();
end;
```

El trabajo fuerte lo hace la el procedimiento `DoSomeWork()`, que en resumen agrega un string grande a un objeto TListString, Tmemo en Form1.

```
procedure TMyWorkerThread.DoSomeWork;
var
  myGranString : String; //String de más de 1000 caracteres
  myLiteralString : String;
  Aleatorio, i : integer;
begin
  Aleatorio := (1+random(10))*1000;
  // tiempo de espera aleatorio entre 1 y 10 segundos
  sleep(Aleatorio);
  myLiteralString := 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer rutrum ligula non turpis semper maximus. Donec ultrices arcu elit. Nam nunc diam, tincidunt nec risus ut, cursus ut venenatis uan at... ';
  myGranString := idHilo+'= ';
  for i:=0 to 4 do
  begin
    myGranString := myGranString+ myLiteralString;
  end;

  Form1.AddHiloTerminado(1);
  Form1.MyStringList.Add(myGranString);
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(myGranString);
end;
```

Cada vez que en Form1 oprimo un botón creo un hilo.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddHiloIncial(1);
  MyWorkerThread := TMyWorkerThread.Create(IntToStr(HiloInicial));
end;
```

Al oprimir un segundo botón, espero que todos los hilos terminen para mostrar un mensaje.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   // Esperar a que terminen todos los hilos.
   while(MyWorkerThread<>nil) and (WaitForSingleObject(MyWorkerThread.Handle, 0)<>WAIT_OBJECT_0) do
   begin
   // esperar a que termine
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   end;

   //MyWorkerThread
   ShowMessage('Termino');
end;
```

> Cuando creo muchos hilos y luego oprimo el segundo botón, sucede que me muestra el mensaje de "Termino" pero el Tmemo aún me sigue mostrando como van ingresando los strings.
>
> 1. ¿Cómo hacer para que el programa espere que el hilo termine todos las operaciones internas como pasar un string a un TListString y a un TMemo?
> 2. ¿Es necesario crear un destructor o el hilo automáticamente se destruye cuando termina?

Comment: Creo que llego algo tarde con la respuesta, pero no había visto esta pregunta antes. Espero sirva de algo todavía. :)

Answer (score 1):

El código que publicas en tu pregunta tiene varios problemas.

## No interactúes con componentes visuales desde hilos secundarios.

Esta es una regla de oro de la programación visual. Delphi no es la excepción. Si quieres hacer algo que afecte la representación visual de la aplicación, debes hacerlo desde el hilo principal. Hay varias estrategias para resolver esto. Por ejemplo, podrías agregar los strings a una lista y que el hilo principal los vaya sacando de allí y agregándolos al memo, por ejemplo, con un timer, o podrías sincronizar la parte del código que hace la interacción visual.

La sincronización, por definición, corre en el hilo principal, y el hilo secundario espera hasta que se ejecute para continuar. En este caso, debes tener cuidado de no provocar un *abrazo mortal* (deadlock, en Inglés). Si el hilo principal está esperando que el hilo secundario termine, y el hilo secundario sincroniza algo, vamos a tener una situación que nunca termina, pues ahora el hilo secundario estará esperando que el hilo principal procese el código sincronizado... provocando que la aplicación *se trabe*.

Ahora, sobre tu pregunta.

## Realmente no estás esperando que terminen todos los hilos

Revisemos este trozo de código, con el que lanzas un nuevo hilo.

> ```
>    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
>    begin
>      AddHiloIncial(1);
>      MyWorkerThread := TMyWorkerThread.Create(IntToStr(HiloInicial));
>    end;
> ```

Supongamos que hago 3 clics seguidos sobre `Button1`, cada vez que se ejecute, la variable MyWorkerThread tendrá la referencia al último hilo creado (únicamente).

Si he creado 3 hilos, tu código, por la manera que está programado, desconoce esta situación, ya que solamente ha guardado la referencia al último hilo. Entonces, el código que realiza la espera, esperará solamente a que termine este hilo.

En un entorno multi-hilos, nada garantiza que el último hilo en iniciar será el último en terminar. Si observas que luego de terminar sigue añadiendo mensajes, es porque hay otros hilos que siguen ejecutándose.

Para resolver esto, si necesitas control sobre hilos individuales, podrías mantener una lista o un vector con las referencias a todos los hilos creados.

Si solo necesitas saber si hay hilos ejecutándose, yo sugiero llevar un contador de hilos activos, y esperar hasta que este contador llegue a 0.

Por ejemplo:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FContadorHilos: Integer;
  public
    procedure IncrementarContadorHilos();
    procedure DecrementarContadorHilos();
    //otros métodos
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.IncrementarContadorHilos();
begin
  //esta llamada garantiza la funcionalidad del incremento en entornos multihilos
  System.AtomicIncrement((FContadorHilos);
end;

procedure TForm1.IncrementarContadorHilos();
begin
  //esta llamada garantiza la funcionalidad del decremento en entornos multihilos
  System.AtomicDecrement((FContadorHilos);
end;
```

Luego, en el hilo:

```
procedure TMyWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  Form1.IncrementarContadorHilos();
  try
    DoSomeWork();
  finally
    Form1.DecrementarContadorHilos();
  end;
end;
```

Utilizo la estructura `try`/`finally` para asegurarme que, sin importar si ocurre un error durante la ejecución del hilo, siempre se ejecute la llamada a `DecrementarContadorHilos()`.

Ahora, esperar a que no haya hilos ejecutándose puede convertirse en algo tan sencillo como:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   // Esperar a que terminen todos los hilos.
   while (FContadorHilos > 0) do
     Application.ProcessMessages; //no recomiendo esto, pero para no enredarnos más

   ShowMessage('Terminó');
end;
```

Finalmente, sobre la destrucción del objeto del hilo, si quieres que se libere de manera automática, pon su propiedad `FreeOnTerminate` en `True`, por ejemplo, en el constructor.

```
constructor TMyWorkerThread.Create(pTxt: string);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(False);
  FidHilo := pTxt;
end;
```

Si no haces esto, queda bajo tu responsabilidad liberar el objeto en el momento apropiado.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el método `WaitFor` de la clases `TThread`, que está pensado justo para lo que necesitas. Según la documentación es justamente para esperar a que el thread termine.
[Método WaitFor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.WaitFor)

Desde esa misma página puedes acceder a esta sección: [Waiting for a Thread to Finish Executing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Waiting_for_a_Thread_to_Finish_Executing), que te explica con un ejemplo práctico cómo usar ese método para esperar a la fiunalización de threads.